# vector in struct causing Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, vector, struct, tree, segmentation-fault

I am trying to build a tree with an unknown number of children for each node. To do this, I construct a struct with a vector of child node in it such that I can grow the size of it as I need.
The following code is how I define the struct:

```
typedef struct Tree_node{
  int item;
  int count;
  struct Tree_node *parent;           //point to the parent node
  vector<struct Tree_node *> child;   //a vector of child node, can grow in size
}TREE_NODE;

typedef struct{
  vector<TREE_NODE *> root;
}FP_TREE;
```

I found articles online saying that vector in struct is perfectly fine. However, when I try to execute the following example code, the terminal shows "segmentation fault"

```
FP_TREE *tree = (FP_TREE *)malloc(sizeof(FP_TREE));
TREE_NODE *test = (TREE_NODE *)malloc(sizeof(TREE_NODE));
tree->root.push_back(test);    //sth wrong here
```

The code is compiled without any error.
I suspect that as the tree's vector grows, it exceeds the size of memory initially allocated to it, causing some potential problem.
Am I missing something or is there a better way to construct this kind of tree?
Very appreciated for any advice.

Comment: Malloc and C++ class types such as vector do not mix. And the rest of your code looks like C. Which C++ textbook are you learning this from?

Comment: Malloc gets you memory. That's all. Not objects. Any attempt to use the return of `malloc` as an object is UB. You need to create an object with new first.

Comment: *"I found articles online"* Curious where these articles are that demonstrate what you're attempting to do in the fashion you're doing it, because they're not worth the electrons they're serving over the web. You do *not* mix `malloc` and non-POD (plain old data) types in C++. Rare is the time you use `malloc/free` in C++ *at all*, much less for something like this.

Comment: just realizing that i'm referencing the C code I wrote before, so i'm using malloc as it is...Thanks for reminding me the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, using malloc the way you are using it is undefined behavior, as it does not perform object initialization, which means that it's not calling the vector's constructor (but there are other things that are not done, as initializing the vtable if there was one, for example).

In your example, you should use new:

```
FP_TREE *tree = new FP_TREE();
TREE_NODE *test = new TREE_NODE();
tree->root.push_back(test);
//This code will leak unless you call delete tree; delete test;
```

But what you really should do in C++ is rely on RAII and avoid raw pointers (use smart pointers, like std::unique_ptr, if you need to work with pointers)

```
FP_TREE tree{};
TREE_NODE test{};
tree.root.push_back(&test);
//Be careful, you can end up with a dangling pointer stored in 
//tree.root if test goes out of scope
```

Comment: just realizing that i'm referencing the C code I wrote before, so i'm using malloc as it is...Thanks for reminding me the difference